# Mac target being built with iphonesimulator gcc 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, build, mixed

In a Mixed 3.2.5 iOS/MacOS project, there is an existing iOS static library target, and I'm adding a MacOS static library. In the target build settings(all configurations) I

- set the Base SDK to "Latest Mac OS X"
- set Architectures to $(NATIVE_ARCH)
- set Valid Architectures to i386 only
- use my own PCH file
- drag headers into Copy Headers, Mac target
- drag source into Compile Sources, Mac target
- add the Foundation.framework found at /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework, set it to the new Mac target

(/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework is also present, but set to the iOS target static lib)

the target compiles but the product appears NOT in "Debug" but in "Debug-iphonesimulator" instead. I'm assuming this is linking to the iOS Foundation? Whatever it's doing I can't assume that's safe.

changing the order of how I add things seems to have no effect.

any suggestions?

Comment: OK I've pretty much come to the conclusion that in a mixed iOS/MacOS static library project you can't depend on Xcode 3.2.5 to generate a binary that is linked to the expected framework.  I can't confirm this, but when a MacOS build product appears in a folder named "Debug-iPhonesimulator" it's pretty suspect to me.  WORKAROUND: Use XCode 4.0.2 or higher. Xcode 4 consistently links to the correct framework.

Comment: I found a solution to this issue in Xcode 3.2.5. Even though you will see preprocessor macro errors in the static library project, create a new project that depends on it(add the mixed static lib project as a dependency). The dependent project will proceed to compile the dependency without issues(even though the mixed static library project can't compile on its own!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest upgrading to Xcode 4. I have projects that build Mac and iOS libraries and both work as expected.